Coloring the rational numbers
All the rationals are coloured with $n$ colours so that, if rationals $a$ and $b$ are colored with different colours then $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is coloured with a colour different from both $a$ and $b$. Prove that every rational is coloured with the same colour. I don't know how to even start with the problem. Can anyone provide any strategies as to how to think about this problem

To get started I suggest trying to show that, if the number of colors isn't $1$, then you need a lot of colors.  Can you rule out $n=2$?   $n=3$?  Further?
